# Contingency code

Tags: c++

Can somebody please let me know, what does contingency code mean...??\

I read it in c++ complete ref, and it related it with virtual functions,
that due to late binding, since calls to virtual functions are resolved at run-time, we dont have to write a lot of "contingency code".
But it did not explain what contingency code meant.

Comment: This is one of those cases where what it's really saying is a lot different from what it seems to be saying. It seems to be saying something about the code, but what it's really saying is that you should throw this book away, and find a better one that actually explains what it means.

Comment: hmm...I've asked many people about a good c++ book, and the majority have given me this books name for a start. My main focus is to learn c++, such that I can use it for competing in programming contests like top coder, etc. Can you help me find a better book that can teach in a way which might be more useful for me in this case??

Answer (score 1):

Ìn this context, a fancier word for 'code with a lot of `if` and `switch` statements', which imperative non-OO code often seems prone to. See [contingency](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/contingency).

Answer (score 0):

Contingency means "A provision for such an event or circumstance" according to Google.  I think he's referring to the fact that derived classes do not have to implement all of the virtual interface of the base class, if there is a definition for the function in the base class (ie, the function is not pure virtual).

This would reduce the amount of "function provision for such objects."

That's my best guess.